# Finding column name where item is closest to given value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the `df`:

```
Index 0_usg 1_usg 2_usg 0_pre 1_pre 2_pre 3_pre
0     1.2   1.1   0.99  2.1   2.5   1.9   1.8
1     1.0   1.1   0.99  2.2   2.5   1.9   2.1  
2     0.9   1.4   0.80  1.9   2.5   1.9   2.0
3     1.3   2.1   1.21  2.6   1.9   1.8   2.3
4     1.5   1.0   0.99  0.9   2.0   1.9   2.0
```

I want to identify the column (among the columns related to `usg`) where the value is closest to 1 and column (among those related to `pre`) where value is closest to 2.

The expected output is:

```
Index usg    pre
0     2_usg  0_pre
1     0_usg  3_pre
2     0_usg  3_pre
3     2_usg  1_pre
4     1_usg  1_pre
```

Note that if two items in two columns are equidistant, you can choose either. How do I get this efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use first [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), then substract `1` and `2`, get [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) with [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
usg = df.filter(like='usg').sub(1).abs().idxmin(axis=1)
pre = df.filter(like='pre').sub(2).abs().idxmin(axis=1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'usg':usg,'pre':pre}, index=df.index, columns=['usg','pre'])
print (df1)
     usg    pre
0  2_usg  0_pre
1  0_usg  2_pre
2  0_usg  3_pre
3  2_usg  1_pre
4  1_usg  1_pre
```

Comment: Found it just after I posted :D
Will mark it as correct, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
In [37]: pd.concat([
            (df.filter(regex='pre') - 2).abs().idxmin(axis=1),
            (df.filter(regex='usg') - 1).abs().idxmin(axis=1)
         ], axis=1)
Out[37]:
       0      1
0  0_pre  2_usg
1  2_pre  0_usg
2  3_pre  0_usg
3  1_pre  2_usg
4  1_pre  1_usg
```